"exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true and node_modules
I've set "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true in my tsconfig.json, but it also applies to all node_modules types, how can i disable any of my tsconfig.json settigs to be applied to node_modules types? Now i am getting an error "... is not assignable to parameter of type '...' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties." because in lib types there is only "?" and in lib's tsconfig.json there is no "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true.
I expect my tsconfig.json doesn't apply to lib's tsconfig.json because i haven't written code there and typescript must respect lib's configs.
